# pass / password store no longer works on my mac and hangs terminal

Tags: terminal, passwords, private-key, public-key

I recently started using password store (https://www.passwordstore.org/) as my password manager on my mac and everything was working flawlessly for weeks. Now everytime I try to use it, it hangs the terminal. This happens whenever I try to show a password or insert a new password. The only way to escape this is to interrupt the program with `Ctrl + C`.
Now I can't access all of my passwords. Does anyone know what might be going on or how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Please read [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

I understand it can be confusing. Such problem can occur due to inconsistent state of GPG agent. To fix it, you'd better refresh GPG agent by running

```
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
```

and then reload the shell: either exit and reopen the shell, or run `exec <YOUR_SHELL>`. Replace `<YOUR_SHELL>` with your shell program, such as `bash`, `zsh`, etc.

Comment: That didn't work for some reason. The problem persists. Any other potential fix?

Comment: Having the same issue on MacOS also. Basically `pass` command takes forever

Comment: This answer helped me. -- https://superuser.com/a/1813317/173271